# Integration in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> First convert into cylindrical coordinates, then compute the integral $$\int_0^2dx\int_0^{\sqrt{2x-x^2}}dy\int_0^az\sqrt{x^2+y^2}dz$$
>
> Source: Demidovich, task 2255

**My work:**

$0\le y\le\sqrt{2x-x^2}\implies 0\le y^2\le 2x-x^2$ and this gives a cylinder $(x-1)^2+y^2\le 1$.

New coordinates:

$$\begin{aligned}x&=r\cos\varphi\\y&=r\sin\varphi\\z&=z,\\\varphi\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]\end{aligned}$$

The Jacobian $J_\psi=r.$

The function $f(x,y,z)=z\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ becomes $\tilde{f}(\varphi,r,z)=zr$

Base of the cylinder in polar coordinates is described by $r\le 2\cos\varphi.$

Then I get the following:

$$\begin{aligned}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{2\cos\varphi}\int_0^azr^2dzdrd\varphi&=\int_0^az\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{2\cos\varphi}r^2drd\varphi\\&=\frac{a^2}2\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{8\cos^3\varphi}3d\varphi\\&=a^2\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{8\cos^3\varphi}3d\varphi\\&=\frac{4a^2}3\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos\varphi(1+\cos(2\varphi))d\varphi\\&=\frac{4a^2}3\int_0^{\pi/2}+\frac{4a^2}3\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos(\varphi)+\cos(3\varphi)}2d\varphi\\&=\frac{4a^2}3+\frac{2a^2}3\left(\sin\varphi+\frac{\sin(3\varphi)}3\right)\Big|_0^{\pi/2}\\&=\frac{4a^2}3+\frac{2a^2}3\frac23\\&=\frac{16}9a^2\end{aligned}$$

The solution in the book is $\frac89a^2.$ Does anyone see my mistake?

Comment: @TeM, thanks! I totally forgot that...